# iOS black screen and MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, mvvmcross

I'm starting to create an app using MvvmCross. So far I have an version for Android and for WP running. Unfortunately, creating the app for iOS isn't easy. When running the iOS-app in the simulator, I only get a black screen. In MonoDevelop's Application Output is see the following exception:

```
2013-01-07 10:42:20.506 BestSellersTouch[319:21e03] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.09 Exception masked MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'.
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.Presenters.MvxTouchViewPresenter.CreateView (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxShowViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.Presenters.MvxTouchViewPresenter.Show (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxShowViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewDispatcher+<>c__DisplayClass4.<RequestNavigate>b__3 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchUIThreadDispatcher+<>c__DisplayClass1.<InvokeOrBeginInvoke>b__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
2013-01-07 10:42:20.508 BestSellersTouch[319:21e03] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Is this error causing a black screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to `System.Type.op_Equality` only exists when an assembly is compiled against `mscorlib.dll` 4.0 (and later).

Current version of MonoTouch does not support 4.0 (and that member is not part of the assembly) which result in this exception at runtime.

The solution, until MonoTouch supports 4.0 (this spring) is to rebuild the assembly and make sure it referenes the `mscorlib.dll` that ships with MonoTouch.

The fact that this exception is thrown while presenting a view is *likely* the reason of your black screen (nothing got executed to show anything on it).

Comment: Do you know how to rebuild MvvmCross and use the mscorlib.dll from MonoTouch? If so, can you tell me or provide a URL?

Comment: I never used MvvmCross myself - but if you create a MonoTouch Library project, from MonoDevelop, you'll get a build that reference the MT mscorlib.dll automagically. If you're using other tools then you have to make sure the right one is referenced.

Comment: this sounds like @poupou has identified the problem at least a bit correctly (he'll know much better than me about the details Monotouch vs Monodroid). I think this is to do with the portable class library projects not quite being portable within Mono yet - they will be at some point, but not yet :( To fix, you can build the MvvmCross dlls for MonoTouch - or my latest ones (an unofficial release) are shared in my skydrive folder http://sdrv.ms/URCbYN - use the folder portableMac on MonoTouch, use the other folders when building on the PC (WP, winrt, MonoDroid)

Comment: Thanks poupou and @Stuart for giving hints and tips. I ran the app with your dlls and it works! Now I have another question: how to build the framework by myself from the github-sources?

Comment: The debug|iPhoneSimulator config of MvvmCross_All should build this set of assemblies for you. For the PC build see some of the PCL-setup posts like http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html - note that Xamarin bug fixes are slowly coming through, and I am trying to get some binary releases out - all takes time...