# Running sample projects in MvvmCross v3 (Hot Tuna)

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to run sample projects (viz. BestSellers and Conference) that are present in [MvvmCross v3 branch](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3). I resolved the strong assembly reference issues successfully. However each time I run a sample project, I get System.TypeLoadException in MvxFullBinding and MvxValueConverterRegistryFiller classes.

Exception in MvxFullBinding class:
[image]

Exception in MvxValueConverterRegistryFiller class:
[image]

Is anybody able to run the sample projects successfully? How do I get around these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running this as the 'Touch' projects from Visual Studio? In which case you are way ahead of what I've managed to achieve.

If that is correct, then I **suspect** that what you are seeing is that you have:

- **built** proper PCLs built in VS/Windows against the portable reference assemblies
- but these cannot be **executed** against the current MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS runtime.

If you try, you may see issues like: [iOS black screen and MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193608/ios-black-screen-and-missingmethodexception-method-not-found-system-type-op-e)

For some more info see 'almost portable binaries' on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/almost-portable-binaries.html

There is 'proper' PCL support currently being worked on within XamLabs - so I am hopeful that there may be a solution to this problem arriving in the Xamarin.Android Alpha channel any day now - but don't expect this to be painless initially.

Of course, I might be wrong on this - this really is new territory and I will be fascinated to hear/read about your adventures. If you want to try to find more detail, then it may help to try looking deeper into the exception details, and looking into the console log trace on your mac.

---

For these two particular exceptions, I can confirm that both samples...

[image: work on my machine]

... although that is **when I'm working on my Mac**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stuart! I just tried running the samples in Xamarin Studio in Mac and was successfully able to do so. Hopefully XamLabs releases PCL support soon, so that we can run it from VS. Meanwhile I'll debug into the code to get more details.

Comment: I was able to get all iOS samples to build and run in both Xamarin/Mac and Xamarin for VS/Windows. Single code base, switching between Mac and VS doesn't even require rebuild. My change was based on Stuart's version 3e922b7756 (4/19): https://github.com/kennethxu/MvvmCross/tree/v3. Trying to sync to the latest was a bit difficult because all samples were moved out of the repo. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Update: synced up to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/3f17c23fd57aed8dbd639d657aa47a9fb94bd86d (4/25) right before samples are moved out.

Comment: Yes I am able to run all samples from @KennethXu's v3 branch from both, Xamarin/Mac and VS/Windows. But I did have to rebuild in both places.